Why do I often see bunches of medical helicopters hovering in clusters in various locations

As you can see in the screenshot there are hovering clusters of medical helicopters in multiple areas. I feel like I see hovering helicopter clusters every time I open the flightradar24 app. I couldn't find anything about this when I googled. Any ideas? Thanks!

Why do bank robbers rob banks? Because that's where the money is.
Why do airplanes cluster at airports? Because that's where the runways and terminals are.
Why do medevac helicopters cluster in certain locations? Because that's where the hospitals are. Hospitals large enough (busy enough) to have helicopter infrastructure are likely to be in dense urban areas, and dense urban areas are likely to have more than just one large hospital.
Helicopters clustering somewhere that isn't a hospital are likely retrieving patients from a mass casualty event like a pile-up on a highway.

That's how they decide where to build an airport, somebody looks around and says "Gee there sure are a lot of airplanes here, we should put in a runway!"

Exactly - they build hospitals near where helicopters roost.

It just seems really inefficient to keep the choppers up in the air doing nothing for so long

@taradevlin are you sure they are hovering, Pittsburgh is a lot bigger than it looks on the map. Or maybe their position is just not properly updated on flight radar.

@tara, I rather doubt that the medical helicopters are hovering. If there is a helicopter hovering it is almost certainly either a TV news crew or a police helicopter doing surveillance.

@taradevlin that website shows every aircraft with a working ADS-B transmitter. Those transmitters are turned on well before takeoff and turned off when the aircraft is shut down. So a helicopter sitting idle on the ground with the engine turning over, waiting for a call (or for takeoff clearance) will have the transmitter running.

@jwenting: That sounds like a key part of the answer to what the OP's really asking, that there seem to always be hovering medical helicopters.  The question already emphasizes "hovering" enough that your comment could pretty much be posted as an answer.

@PeterCordes possibly. I was on hotel internet when commenting, using a tablet screen, so not really suitable for writing longer things than a comment.

Also most "base of operatiojns" places (in many european, belgium, netherlands germany) countries for helicopters are not hospitals: hospitals are where patients go to and need good road connections.  Helicopters just need to be central, they are often used to bring personel, not transport patients; As such thy are often centrally at their own "spot" with its own team.
